# UWP page loading time slower during page navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a XAML page that creates a grid of 48x48 images (a collage of images). When the user navigates to this page, I load the config for the collage, and add items to the Grid in C# and set their `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` fields. Something like this:

```
private void InitializeGrids()
{
    // Set row definitions and column definitions
    // ...

    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimensions; j++)
        {
            var cell = new ImageCell()
            {
                Row = i,
                Column = j
            };
            Grid.SetRow(cell, i);
            Grid.SetColumn(cell, (j * 10));
            Contents.Children.Add(cell);
        }
    }
}
```

When the user navigates to this page on a button click from a different page, I see a good visible delay of around 8-10 seconds.

Where as, if I load the page directly at startup, the app loads fine in a couple of seconds.

Any reason why adding elements on page navigation takes a lot of time?

Comment: Do you have anything in Navigation events? Something that is happening in the background? Have you tried to play with *NavigationCacheMode* of your Page?

Comment: Is the `InitializeGrids` method the one taking 8-10 seconds to finish executing? Are you loading any images as you are navigating to that page? Who is calling the `InitializeGrids` method?

Answer (score 0):

For I think ImageCell use too more time that you should let the UI to respond in Navigate.

In WinForm, we can use PushFrame that we should do some cost some UI thread resource. But in UWP that we can use `Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync`

Try use the code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dimensions; j++)
            {
                await Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync(o =>
                {
                    var cell = new ImageCell()
                    {
                        Row = i,
                        Column = j
                    };
                    Grid.SetRow(cell, i);
                    Grid.SetColumn(cell, j);
                    Grid.Children.Add(cell);
                });
            }
        }
```